# How can I change the version of Java used in Bluemix?

Tags: java, cloud, ibm-cloud

I have an old legacy Java app that I am trying to run in Bluemix.  I would like to use either Java 1.5 or Java 1.6.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the Java buildpack, the Java buildpack is available at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.

To use it when you deploy your app you can either add it to `manifest.yml` or use the Cloud Foundry CLI to specify the buildpack.  You can do that with the following.

```
cf push myappname -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
```

**manifest.yml**

```
applications:
- path: .
  memory: 512MB
  instances: 1
  domain: mybluemix.net
  name: myappname
  host: myappname
  disk_quota: 1024M
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
```

Once you deploy your app with that buildpack you can specify the version of Java with the following command.

```
cf set-env myappname JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE '{jre: { version: 1.7.0_+ }}'
```

You can then change the version of Java for your app by changing `1.7.0` to whatever version you want.

You will need to restart/restage your app after you change the Java version though.  You can do this with the following.

```
cf restage myappname
```

Comment: You can also set environment variables directly in the manifest.yml file with an env block (see https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#env-block).  This will ensure the env var is set as part of the `cf push` and avoids the extra `cf set-env` and `cf restage` steps