# Specify JDK's version in pom.xml or manifest.yml?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have an java application which I would like to deploy it to cloud foundry. And I want to specify the JDK version of it. I searched some articles but I'm confused where to do it.

In some articles it says that I need to use java-buildpack and specify the environment in manifest.yml or in cf command. e.g. [How can I change the version of Java used in Bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187071/how-can-i-change-the-version-of-java-used-in-bluemix)

But some others say that I could specify the JDK version in pom.xml with -source and -target properties. e.g. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Can anyone tell me the difference and which one should I choose?

Comment: The settings in your `pom.xml` are merely values that the `javac` compiler uses during compilation, it's entirely unrelated to wherever you're trying to deploy to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the JRE version with your application `manifest.yml` file.

The java buildpack currently supports [OpenJDK](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/jre-open_jdk_jre.md), [Oracle](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/jre-oracle_jre.md) or [Azul Zulu](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/jre-zulu_jre.md) JREs. Assuming you are using OpenJDK, JRE versions `1.6`, `1.7` and `1.8` are supported out-of-the-box by the buildpack.

To set the JRE version just specify an environment variable in your application manifest as follows:

```
---
applications:
- name: my-java-app
  memory: 512M
  env:
    JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: '{ jre: { version: 1.8.0_+ } }'
```

The java buildpack does not look at the `pom.xml` file. It assumes you deploy a compiled version of your app (e.g. a JAR or WAR file.)

Comment: Two notes: 1.) Unless you have a really good reason you shouldn't set the version of the JDK to be installed by the build pack.  In general, build pack's will install the latest version of the software.  This is one of the nice things about build packs, auto upgrades.  If you pick a specific version of the JDK, like 1.8.0_131 then you won't get additional updates.  You're frozen there.  If you use the `+` at the end like in this example (Java BP specific), you'll get updates to the minor version.  This is somewhat better, but generally you shouldn't meddle.

Comment: 2.) Setting the version of the JDK in manifest.yml is no different than using `cf set-env JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE '{ jre: { version: 1.8.0_+ } }'`.  They're both setting an environment variable at which the Java build pack will look to determine the version to install.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some of the comments in this post, I was able to set the target jdk in pcf by using this command from PCF CLI

```
$ cf set-env <app-name> JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE '{ jre: { version: 11.0.6_10 } }
```