# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError when deploy on PCF

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, cloud-foundry

I recently updated java version of a springboot project from 8 to 11.

Then I navigate to the subproject folder main_project/event_producer, login to PCF, then pushed it to PCF with following command (cf8 push event-producer -m 2G -b java_buildpack -p target\event-producer-2.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar).

However, the deployed app crashed with error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/gm/cca/kafka/EventProducerApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

This is my first time deploy on PCF. Is there anyway to solve this error?

Comment: You could try setting source to 1.8 and target to 1.8 in your compiler and rebuild

Comment: Seems it's more or less answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533252/specify-jdks-version-in-pom-xml-or-manifest-yml

Comment: Agree with @JockX, that's the answer.

Comment: Thank you guys. But I'm required to using java 11 with my project. I cannot downgrade it to 1.8

Comment: @JockX Thanks! I followed one of the answer using '$ cf set-env <app-name> JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE '{ jre: { version: 11.0.6_10 } }' command and it works.